# Why did Miranda die in my playthrough?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

Okay, I did everything for her to live: I met her 3 times, warned her about Kai Leng, (which happens automatically when you meet up with her via video conference in the Spectre Office), and also I gave her the Alliance resources.

I didn't romance her in 2 or 3 because my Shepard is female and, I'm sure we're friends. In my ME2 save, she was loyal and survived the Suicide mission.

I chose the paragon option when I met Henry Lawson. He let Oriana go but Miranda still dies. I also tried the exact same thing but with choosing the Renegade option at the end, to no avail.

So I went far back to my save where FemShep just finish the mission about the Catalyst and Kai Leng stole that Prothean Tech. I thought how quickly you do the Sanctuary mission affected the outcome of Miranda's life - either she dies or lives, but that didn't do anything.

So here, I searched up all the possible ways and the topics on Miranda surviving. I even went to Youtube for that and even searched for cheats but really, nothing came up. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You talk about Miranda dying like it's a bad thing...

Comment: I like Miranda. And I lost Legion and Mordin already, I don't want to lose more characters.

Comment: activate all video terminal in santcuary, chose "I just want Oriana" & Renegade interrupt shooting Oriana leg.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [German Mass Effect Wiki](http://de.masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Miranda_Lawson#Horizon) you have to tell her to talk to Oriana during her Loyalty Mission in ME2. If you didn't tell her to talk to Oriana Miranda always dies in ME3.

I can't find anything about this in the English Mass Effect Wiki and can't confirm it myself right now. So it would be great if somebody can check and confirm it.

Comment: I did. I made Miranda talk to Oriana in my ME2 save. I really don't know what's wrong... I already lost Legion and Mordin, and I didn't have the Kasumi DLC, so Kasumi is out of the picture. I hope BioWare sleeps soundly after killing many main characters just for plot.

Comment: @user107933 Don't watch Game of Thrones then if this upsets you already :p

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to watch it. Apart from the extensive word count from the book and many characters, and really confusing timeline, I'm not a diplomat or into politics. My brother reads it but, um, I sneaked a peek and, there was a warning about the timeline. Also, the asshole, Joffrey. Not that I hate it but, it's not for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to meet her at the Docks on the Citadel before the Cerberus attack.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether it is possible to save her as just a friend. In my recent playthrough my Shepard had relationship with her in ME2, which they continued in ME3. I met her 3 times, warned her about Leng, supported her with allies resources, had sex, etc. By the Sanctuary mission I chose neither Paragon nor Renegade option. I chose the "we just need Oriana" option. After that pushed the Renegade button and shot Oriana on her leg. After that Miranda pushed her father out of the window and she stayed alive.

Comment: Of course you can save Miranda as a friend. Otherwise she would be doomed for all the femsheps.

Comment: If you say so. I never saved her as a female Shepard, so I cannot be sure about that. If you are right then most probably choosing the option I mentioned and then the renegade interrupt is the way to go.